# Check if button clicked has ID that starts with a particular String in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and have the following code

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a id="id_btn_dropdown_policies" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"   href="#">
                        --Select-- </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#" id="id_btn_dropdown_policy_policy1">policy1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id_btn_dropdown_policy_policy2">policy2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id_btn_dropdown_policy_policy3">policy3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id_btn_dropdown_policy_policy4">policy4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my function is

```
$(function() {

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
        //check if button clicked is of id that starts with id_btn_dropdown_policy
        $("#id_btn_dropdown_policies").text($(this).text());
        $("#id_btn_dropdown_policies").val($(this).text());
        getCategory($(this));
    });

});
```

I want setting the text and value of element with id id_btn_dropdown_policies only if `this.id.indexof("id_btn_dropdown_policies")=0`

I am not able to do this in jQuery because looks like there is no indexof method. I tried

```
if($(this).attr('id').indexof("id_btn_dropdown_policy") == 0) {
                alert("Matched");
            };
```

which is not correct. So what is the correct way?

Comment: Please, stick with the DOM approach for this: `this.id.indexOf('yourString') === 0`, there's no need to invoke jQuery to assess a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `indexof` method indeed, it's **`indexOf`** (capital 'O') you're looking for.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 2):

You may try following handler instead (Register your handler only for those `a` tags whose id begins with `id_btn_dropdown_policy`):

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a[id^='id_btn_dropdown_policy']").click(function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

In this case, `a[id^='id_btn_dropdown_policy']` means that, all a tags whose `id` begins with `id_btn_dropdown_policy`. So clicking on other `a` tags won't take any action.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a[id^='id_btn_dropdown_policy']")
```

is a crapy selector you should use `indexOf` method of javascript.

i.e

```
if($(this).attr('id').indexOf("id_btn_dropdown_policy") == 0) {
                alert("Matched");
            };
```

My suggestion will be `use common class` for those div and then select by classs selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I understand your question, but you can use the "[attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector in jQuery to make your selections.

```
$(function () {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        //check if button clicked is of id that starts with id_btn_dropdown_policy
        $( "[id^='id_btn_dropdown_policies']" ).text($(this).text());
        $( "[id^='id_btn_dropdown_policies']" ).val($(this).text());
        getCategory($(this));
    });
});
```